# Giving zero when calling for constant in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the code in ASM:

```
mov al, VGA_WIDTH * 2
mov dl, byte [Y]
mul dl
```

VGA_WIDTH is constant equal to 60 and Y is a byte equal to 3, when I multiply them I get zero(well ) i can assume, when I add the eax(the answer) to the offset it simply doesn't change the offset.

I have similar code to this that works perfectly fine I just dont understand why this doesn't.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. Also, produce an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

These are some pointers to consider:

- Is the `DS` segment register setup to address the *Y* variable?
- The instruction `mul dl` gives a result in the `AX` register, yet you talk about "the `eax` (the answer)". Misinterpreting the result?

Comment: Thank you for answering the ds register was pointing to a gdt table that I had setup for tty in that routine i fixed it.

Comment: and you can access ax with eax but the top 16 bist are zero or what every previously had been stored in eax